# Perform jQuery only if form is valid

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I'm using the jQuery validate plugin and I'm also using jQuery to make a closing animation for a popup that my form is in.

Naturally, I don't want the popup to close if the form is invalid and errors need fixed.

Here's what I'm working with...

Form validation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").validate({
       errorContainer: "#messageBox1",
       errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox1 ul",
       wrapper: "li",
    });
    });
```

Submit form button action:

```
$("#ContinueButton").click(function(){
$("#refer-a-friend").animate({
    top: "0%",
    opacity: 0
}, 500 );
});
```

So how would I make it so the close animation only fires if the form is valid?

Answer (score 1):

Your validation will be run when `#form` is submitted. Your `#ContinueButton` needs to either be `type="submit"`, or call `$("#form").submit();`

Once you have the button submit firing the validation, take a look at the **submitHandler** option in the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options), it should be what you need. Something like this:

```
$("#form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      //perform your animation here 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ContinueButton").click(function(){
   if($("#form").valid()) {
      $("#refer-a-friend").animate({
         top: "0%",
         opacity: 0
       }, 500 );
   }
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid